# Is there a word that means "a nicer word for a word"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that I learned when studying for the CLEP analysing and interpreting literature exam. It is a word that means -'a more eloquent version of a harsher word.

Example: saying, 'expecting' instead of 'pregnant'

Comment: The title contradicts the body, the title is asking for a word that is harsher (derogatory) version of  word while the body is asking for a word that is a  "softer version"

Comment: You have also used a *double comparative* (less nicer). Notwithstanding Shakespeare's having used them, they are not considered grammatical in modern English. It either needs to be *less nice*, or *nicer*.

Answer (score 9):

***Euphemism***: "a mild or indirect word or expression substituted for one considered to be too harsh or blunt when referring to something unpleasant or embarrassing."  [Google euphemism](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=euphemism)

Euphemism: "the substitution of an agreeable or inoffensive expression for one that may offend or suggest something unpleasant"

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euphemism

Comment: Like saying someone *passed away*, when they died.

Comment: Yeah, the etymology is almost literal:  Greek for "good speech".

Comment: I added the link.  Please cite your reference and add a link from now on.

Comment: @ab2 Is your comment addressed to me? I'm new on the site, and am slightly confused. In a similar answer I provided, a definition, my comment was edited by the site, and  the link I provided was deleted, which is why I didn't provide a link this time. From now on, I will, thank you.

Comment: @CathyGartaganis that's unfortunate. Why were they removed?

Comment: @ab2: A link to a reputable source is certainly a good thing though not strictly necessary. Google Dictionary is not really a reputable source [Is Google Dictionary a valid source?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7052/8019): a link to a Google search is practically useless. Also, please be careful about giving instructions without reasons: the irony of giving such instructions about citations is almost overwhelming.

Comment: @NVZ I'm not computer savvy, nor am I familiar with all the variations of links. If I want to answer a question, I try to find a link to support my answer. Perhaps my links aren't reliable. I leave it to the site to decide. My concern is to help the person asking the question.

Comment: @CathyGartaganis it's fine. The more you learn, the fewer mistakes you'll make. Although my account is 2 yrs old, I only started using SE recently. So I understand you well.

Comment: @Cathy Gartaganis: +1 for providing a reference with a better link.  Hint: to make your link look neater enter: [what you want highlighted](address of link)   When the address is short, it doesn't make much difference, but when the address is long, it looks much better.

Comment: @ab2 Don't kill me - I don't understand your instructions. I'm an idiot when it comes to computers. I barely know how to send an email. The only way I know how to copy/paste is to make the URL turn blue.

Comment: @Cathy Gartaganis  Sorry, I have no desire to kill or distress you!  Check out Sue's answer to my question about neat looking links at http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/688/purely-technical-question-about-putting-a-link-in-a-q-or-an-a    If this doesn't help....don't worry about it.

Comment: @ab2 Thank you. I'll show my cousin those instructions next time I see her.