# When you hate to name something so you use an alternative word

Tags: vocabulary

When you prefer to use another word rather than the actual word or phrase like when you don't want to addmitt something or you want to criticise something or someone

Comment: please elaborate.  Use a sample sentence or phrase if you need to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a word that means "a nicer word for a word"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/318670/is-there-a-word-that-means-a-nicer-word-for-a-word)

Comment: ***genteelism***:a word or expression used because it is thought to be socially more acceptable than the everyday word.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about **a euphemism**?

> a mild or indirect word or expression substituted for one considered to be too harsh or blunt when referring to something unpleasant or embarrassing. ([source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/euphemism))